# Появляется ошибка JSON при изменении постоянных ссылок wordpress

Tags: wordpress

При изменении постоянных ссылок на любые кроме простых, появляется ошибка: "ошибка публикации. ответ не является допустимым ответом json."

В консоли также есть ошибка, на скриншоте ниже: [image: Ошибка Rest API]

Wordpress поставлен на Openserver, после установки никаких изменений не было.

Comment: Похоже на неправильный .htaccess: https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Comment: попробовал поставить тот, что рекомендуется, изменений нет

Comment: Деактивировать все плагины по одному, сменить тему на стандартную.

Comment: Во первых тексты ошибок, равно как и код и другие тексты, нужно давать текстами, а не картинками. А во вторых - это при публикации из админки или стороннего приложения?

Comment: Ида, https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/ может помочь разобраться

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на "похожие" вопросы в теме wordpress.

Дело в том, что движок для каждой странички формирует объект,- он должен быть включен структуру сайта, и ссылки на объекты формируются по определенным правилам.

Поэтому нет возможности просто изменить ссылку.
Для изменения правил формирования url ссылок нужно обратиться к настройкам, если вам доступна административная панель сайта.

Comment: Так-с.. Но выходит, что если я изменяю постоянные ссылки, например, на "название записи", то я как раз-таки и изменяю правила формирования url?.. Или же я не так это понял

Comment: Через админку. Админка-Настройки-Постоянные ссылки. И там можно задать шаблон\переопределить текущий.

Comment: Я так и делал. Всё по-прежнему

Comment: полнейшая чушь.

Comment: @SeVlad вангую, там есть плагин "оптимизации" REST :)

Comment: @KAGGDesign у ТСа - допускаю (но в вопросе не указано), но я ответчице написал.